# android - Обработка нажатий списка, запуск прогрессбара, хранилище прогрессов

Tags: android, listview, progress-bar

Всем привет :) В моей практике впервые встала такая задача. Я делаю простенький симулятор.

Есть ListView, заполняю его через SimpleAdapter, на переднем плане айтема текст действия (например, съесть сосиску). На заднем плане - прогрессбар во весь айтем, который служит ему "фоном". С самого начала все прогрессбары стоят с прогрессом 100. Когда игрок нажимает на " сьесть сосиску" прогрессбар сбрасывается на 0 и начинает потихоньку расти до конца. Когда он растет, игрок не может нажать повторно, он ждет. А когда прогрессбар дойдет до конца, заполнив собой весь фон айтема, действие можно **повторить**. Таких действий - немало. Тоесть, игрок может нажать на несколько айтемов и они должны доходить до конца, без сбоев.

Все, бы хорошо, если не всем известная "особенность" этих списков в android - если запустить прогрессбар и сдвинуть его за экран, то при возвращении прогресс сам ставится на 100. Нужно дополнить мой адаптер, но я не знаю **как**?

Я примерно представляю, как это должно работать:

1) Создать массив `int` значений, в котором будут находиться прогрессы

2) В слушателе списка менять значение в этом массиве по позиции нажатого айтема на **0**

3) Далее, в слушателе, запускать `CountDownTimer`, который в методе `onTick` каждый раз будет менять значение в массиве прогрессов

4) И адаптер. В методе `getView` присваивать прогресс из массива, так же, по позиции

Как это реализовать? У меня: **при скроллинге прогресс сбрасывается на 100**

У меня ничего не получается, помогите :(

Comment: Тут проблема видимо в кэширование данных. У меня была схожая проблема при попытке отображать разные view в списках. Перейдите на использование RecyclerView. Там больше вариантов настроек...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте при нажатии на элемент списка выставлять для него (для вьюшки данного элемента)

```
setHasTransientState(true);
```

При заполнении прогресса соответственно выставить false.

Comment: Пожалуйста. Если знаете английский, то тут подробнее https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8MIfSxgsHIs&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc86y1CjAlexivfvOms6_0NC&index=3